# R trouble with substitute when formula writing

Tags: r

I'd like to iterate over a formula where the independent variable is passed as a string. I'm using substitute and expression but don't know why it's failing.

Please see the following:

```
> coxph(substitute(survivalOutcome ~ x, list(x = as.name(colnames(combinedData)[1]))), data = combinedData)
Error in terms.default(formula, special, data = data) : 
  no terms component nor attribute


> substitute(survivalOutcome ~ x, list(x = as.name(colnames(combinedData)[1])))
survivalOutcome ~ PMM2

> coxph(survivalOutcome ~ PMM2, data = combinedData)
Call:
coxph(formula = survivalOutcome ~ PMM2, data = combinedData)


       coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z    p
PMM2 0.0445      1.05    0.146 0.305 0.76

Likelihood ratio test=0.09  on 1 df, p=0.761  n= 206, number of events= 129 
> 
> colnames(combinedData)[1]
[1] "PMM2"
```

As you can see, the expression matches up perfectly, but I don't know why it fails?

Comment: you'll probably have better luck with `?reformulate`

Comment: you're right -- I did. Still curious about the above though..